# How to store a variable in a header, to use in the main cpp?

Tags: c++

I tried asking this question, it was a bit more fuzzy on the details, but now I arrived home and I hope I can explain myself better.

Say, I have  a class, in this case, `TestClass`, I declared its constructor and methods in `TestClass.h` already. Now, I want to create a new array of these elements, and store them somewhere, to load in to my `main.cpp`, when I want to.

What I tried doing, is, doing this in a new header, I called `Contents Table.h`. Here, I tried making an array of these `TestClass` elements. However, I don't really know, how to go about properly doing this.

Testclass.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestClass
{
private:
    string name;
    string description;
public:
    TestClass()
    {
        name = "";
        description = "";
    }
    TestClass(string name, string description)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->description = description;
    }
    ~TestClass()
    {
    }
};
```

And here is the Contents Table, where I want to store my data, that I manually write in, I had two ideas about doing this, not sure which one is feasible:

First idea:

ContentsTable.h

```
#include "Testclass.h"

TestClass* buildData(void)
{
    TestClass* World = new TestClass[5];
    World[0] = TestClass("A", "A");
    //Etc, fill the rest up.
    return World;
}
```

And in the main.cpp, I'd call this function, like

```
#include "Contents Table.h"

//...

TestClass* DataArray = buildData();
```

Second idea:

ContentsTable.h

```
#include "Testclass.h"

namespace DataArray2
{
    extern TestClass* DataArray2 = new TestClass[5];
    DataArray2[0] = TestClass("A", "A");
};
```

And I'd declare it again in the main.cpp, but the second one things, I'm trying to redeclare the DataArray2, when I try giving one if its elements value. (Again, I'm sure it's my fault with this, sorry, if it seems like a really banal code, I haven't been learning for long.)

Comment: I prefer the first way, but you don't need to use pointers.

Comment: I'd love to try both, see which is better, but I just can't get the second to work, because the rookie I am, I can't seem to find out, how to modify the elements of the array.

Comment: I suggest using `std::vector<TestClass>` instead of an array of raw pointers.

Comment: you should research the Singleton pattern. there are many pitfalls in defining and using global variables (arrays or otherwise) and you should probably avoid it.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I think singletons are globals in all but name. So, to the OP - what did you try when you attempted approach 2? What went wrong when you try to modify elements? BTW - who will delete the array "afterwards" - whenever afterwards is for global data?

Comment: Also, the `buildData` function would need to be declared inline to be defined in a header, and avoid `using namespace std;` in a header

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this meets your requirements, but I'd make `buildData` look like this (C++11 solution):

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

/*Define TestClass*/

vector<TestClass> buildData() {
    vector<TestClass> v;
    v.emplace_back("A", "A");
    return v;
}
```